# How do I read the value of PHP sess_ files?

Tags: php, session, debian, sessionid

At localhost (Debian Sid machine), PHP creates session files in /var/lib/php5. When I open sess_cd2ct9hud284gn01os13nk5mi7, for example, i can see something like that:

```
Qms6wztHQ9u79B7jjiihLX0cKc_fXgwo0NeVE34jFhdE__1JDOliUDteHQVXgMAjcGZgJ1EkBft0IUsqBdWrck7s0Vjghsm3vk681u_GV8KRK-ExrAEbvbgXfl51Z83tyh5h2JtRy0qLZmhqwLtUFykm1XbdBBxx5xJpNpg4z_ccvOW2-k947-pn_L40lK_ZybK-9gTvD3giGy9pvtNHAoFuUE0KLH9kE87vTWKt4pbf-Upm3_VGLyu5yCqkWAxfJHILmlb1wAqfIssnS632YA..
```

How could I read the real value of the session using this file? Is this a base64_hash?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the "name" or the id of the session you could read it within PHP.

```
// $oldName = session_name( "[session name here]" );
$oldId = session_id(); session_id( "[new id]" );
session_start();

// Do something..
var_dump( $_SESSION );

// Get back to first session
// session_name( $oldName );
session_id( $oldId );
session_start();
```

You could also try the [`session_decode()`](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php) function, which loads the contents of a serialized session into the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

sess_cd2ct9hud284gn01os13nk5mi7
cd2ct9hud284gn01os13nk5mi7
this is the session id, its in the name of the file

Comment: OK, i got it. But how could i see the session value with the sess_cd2ct9hud284gn01os13nk5mi7 file's content?